# Função RANDOM no BD IBM Informix?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, random, informix

Preciso utilizar uma função random() no SQL em um banco de dados Informix versão 11.50.
Porém no select abaixo retorna erro de sintaxe :

```
select random(), codigo from minha_tabela; 
  674: Routine (random) can not be resolved.
Error in line 1
Near character position 8
```

A função não existe ou tem outro meio de utiliza-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função random() só foi adicionada nativamente no banco IBM Informix na versão 11.70.xC6 através de uma ["package" de compatibilidades](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_dbxt_530.htm) com o Oracle (usando o recurso de *datablades* do Informix).

Porém é possível criar a sua própria função random nas versões anteriores do banco.
Para isso basta ter permissão de criação de SPL/UDRs ou solicitar ao seu DBA para criar o codigo abaixo.

## Versão 11.70 xC5 ou inferior

A autoria deste código é de [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) (ex-IBM) e sua versão original pode ser encontrado no [repositório de códigos](http://www.iiug.org/software/archive/random_spl) do [IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/) (International Informix User Group).

Exemplo executado através do utilitário dbaccess:

```
-- @(#)$Id: random.spl,v 1.2 1997/12/08 19:31:44 johnl Exp $
--
-- Simple emulation of SRAND and RAND in SPL
-- Using random number generator suggested by C standard (ISO 9899:1990)

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_setseed(n INTEGER)
        DEFINE GLOBAL seed DECIMAL(10) DEFAULT 1;;
        LET seed = n;;
END PROCEDURE;
Routine created.

;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_random() RETURNING INTEGER;;
        DEFINE GLOBAL seed DECIMAL(10) DEFAULT 1;;
        DEFINE d DECIMAL(20,0);;
        LET d = (seed * 1103515245) + 12345;;
        -- MOD function does not handle 20-digit values...  Dammit!!
        LET seed = d - 4294967296 * TRUNC(d / 4294967296);;
        RETURN MOD(TRUNC(seed / 65536), 32768);;
END PROCEDURE;
Routine created.

;
execute procedure sp_setseed(3414311);
Routine executed.

select first 15 sp_random(), tabid from systables
(expression)       tabid

       20738           1
       14601           2
       22109           3
        2879           4
       24494           5
       27611           6
       30188           7
       30057           8
        6287           9
        1852          10
       18407          11
       13089          12
       24552          13
       30206          14
        8225          15
15 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
```

## Versão 11.70 xC6 ou superior

Nesta versão já é possível utilizar a função `DBMS_RANDOM_RANDOM()`.
Mas para isso é preciso antes registrar o *datablade* "SQL Packages Extension" (excompat).

*** **Observação**: Apesar de na versão 11.70 xC1 já existir o recurso de registrar automaticamente os *datablades built-in* , ele não registra o excompat, sendo necessário registra-lo manualmente. Mas isso deve ser feito apenas uma vez e vale dentro do banco de dados conectado.  ***

```
-- Exibindo a versao que esto utilizando
select dbinfo('version','full') from sysmaster:sysdual;
(constant)
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC7
1 row(s) retrieved.

-- Registrando o datablade excompat (SQL Extension compatible)
execute function sysbldprepare('excompat.1.0', 'create');
(expression)
           0
1 row(s) retrieved.

-- Comparando random SPL com random built-in do Informix ;
select first 15 sp_random(), dbms_random_random() , tabid from systables ;

(expression) (expression)       tabid
       16838  -1109799718           1
        5758   1761650943           2
       10113  -2067931720           3
       17515    462500326           4
       31051   1464472358           5
        5627  -2047557286           6
       23010    356861852           7
        7419  -1157266724           8
       16212   1202317650           9
        4086  -1302274873          10
        2749    186851740          11
       12767   1161898564          12
        9084  -1151907315          13
       12060    755693317          14
       32225  -1420713979          15
15 row(s) retrieved.
```